# C#: What `using` statement do I need here?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a project in MS Visual Studio 2008 Pro. I'm new to the environment and the language, so forgive a noobish question.

I have a type `ControlCode`:

```
namespace ShipAILab
{
    public abstract class ControlUnit {

        public enum ControlCode {
            NoAction = 0x00, 
            MoveLeft = 0x01,
            MoveUp = 0x02,
            MoveRight = 0x04,
            MoveDown = 0x08,
            Fire = 0x10,
        }

    }
}
```

I want this to be accessible from another class, `BoardUtils`, which is in the same `ShipAILab` namespace:

```
    public static IList<ControlUnit.ControlCode> pathToPoint(IDictionary<CompPoint, int> dist, CompPoint destination) {
          ControlUnit.ControlCode code = ControlUnit.ControlCode.MoveLeft; // works
          ControlCode c2 = ControlCode.MoveDown; // how do I get this to work?
    }
```

Why doesn't this work automatically, by virtue of sharing a namespace? Do I need a `using` statement? Can I "typedef" it like in C to rename `ControlUnit.ControlCode` to something more concise?

Comment: You might want to decorate the enumeration with the [FlagAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) adding `[Flag]` before the enumeration definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your enumeration is *inside* the `ControlUnit` class.

If you want it to be accessible without typing the class name, move the enumeration outside the class.

Answer (score 4):

Move the enum to outside the class.

```
namespace ShipAILab
{
    public enum ControlCode {
        NoAction = 0x00, 
        MoveLeft = 0x01,
        MoveUp = 0x02,
        MoveRight = 0x04,
        MoveDown = 0x08,
        Fire = 0x10,
    }

    public abstract class ControlUnit {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a using statement if they're in the same namespace.

Are they in the same dll (same project under VS2008). If not, then you'll need to add a reference from the `pathToPoint` dll to the one that declares `ControlUnit`. You can do this by finding the project in the solution explorer, right clicking on it, and picking 'Add Reference...'

#### Update

If the code as shown does actually compile, and you want to make it so you don't have to type `ControlUnit.XYZ` all over the place, then you need to move the declaration of the enum *outside* the `ControlUnit` class